# Can you output map values in visualforce inline using a string key?

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, controller-extension

Can you output a value from a map in a custom extension without  or it being in a table? Tried the below and did not work.

example extension:

```
public without sharing class Example {
public List<Custom_Object__c> records {get; set;}
public Map<String,Custom_Object__c> map {get; set;}
public String recId {get; set;}
public Example(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    recId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    records =
    [select Name, field1__c,field2__c,field3__c from Custom_Object__c where Id=:recId ];
    Map<String, Custom_Object__c> map = new Map<String, Custom_Object__c>();

    String key;
    for(Custom_Object__c record :records) {

        if(record.field3__c.contains('foo')) {
            key = 'foo_'+Name;
        }else{
            key = 'bar_'+Name;
        }
        if(record!=null) {
            map.put(key, record);
        }

    }

}
}
```

display values like below in visualforce.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <apex:outputText value="{!map['foo test'].field1}"/>. <br/>
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem <apex:outputText value="{!map['bar test2'].field2}"/>...
</p>
```

Comment: What happened i.e. exactly how did it not work?

Comment: You have a local variable called `map` in your constructor that hides the `map` property. Change `Map<String, Custom_Object__c> map = new Map...` to  `map = new Map...` so you are assigning to the property in the constructor. The pattern you are using does work.

Comment: Thanks Keith, thats exactly what it was.

Comment: I've posted that as an answer; accept it and then others won't be distracted thinking you still need an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a local variable called `map` in your constructor that hides the `map` property. (See e.g. [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) for more about that.)

Change:

```
Map<String, Custom_Object__c> map = new Map<String, Custom_Object__c>();
```

to:

```
map = new Map<String, Custom_Object__c>();
```

so you are assigning to the property in the constructor, not just the local variable.

The pattern you are using - a string keyed map - does work.